# Firebase Hosting and Expo Web: How to deploy Expo web build to Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, expo, firebase-hosting, circleci

I am currently attempting to deploy my Expo application to Firebase hosting, however my build uses the default `index.html` given by Firebase and my Expo's `web-build/index.html` is sitting and not being used. Is there a way to use my expo web build instead of Firebase's index.html? Please help and give me some insight :)

**CircleCI config**

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.17.0
    working_directory: ~/repo
    steps:
      - checkout
      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: yarn
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-npm-deps-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
          paths:
            - ./node_modules
      - run:
          name: Install Expo
          command: yarn global add expo-cli
      - run:
          name: Login into Expo
          command: npx expo-cli login -u <EXPO USERNAME> -p <EXPO PASSWORD>
      - run:
          name: Build
          command: expo build:web --non-interactive --no-pwa
      - run:
          name: Firebase Deploy
          command: ./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --token <FIREBASE TOKEN> --only hosting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup Firebase incorrectly, when running `firebase init`, I did not update my default path for the `index.html`.

[Followed the Expo deployment documentation](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/publishing-websites/)